# $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ iid $N(0, \sigma^2)$ Find the value of c in order for it to have size $\alpha$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

$x_1, \cdots, x_n$ iid $N(0, \sigma^2)$ and we're testing the hypothesis

$H_0: \sigma^2= \sigma_{o}^{2}$

$H_1: \sigma^2= \sigma_{1}^{2}$

$\sigma_{0}^{2} > \sigma_{1}^{2}$

Im given the decision function to be

$\delta(x_1, \cdots, x_n)= 1$ if $T\leq c$ or $0$ if $T > c$

with $T=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}$

I was told to find the distribution of $\frac{T}{\sigma_{o}^{2}}$ but I'm pretty sure its just $Ga(\frac{n}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$

The next problem though is I have to find the value of c in order for it to have size $\alpha$ and all I have is

P(reject $H_0$|$\sigma^2$)=P($T \leq c$) = P($\frac{T}{\sigma_{o}^{2}} \leq \frac{c}{\sigma_{o}^{2}}$)

I know that $\frac{T}{\sigma_{o}^{2}}$~$Gamma(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2})=\chi^2$ but after that Im not sure how to solve for c

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a table or some software if you want to find a value. Let $k=c/\sigma^2_0$ and $T/\sigma^2_0=W$. You want to solve:

$$
Pr(\text{Rejection}|H_0\text{ is true})=\alpha \Leftrightarrow Pr(W\leq k)=\alpha\\\int_0^k\frac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}w^{\frac{n}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{w}{2}}dw=\alpha
$$

and I don't think there's a closed form solution to that integral. But, when you know the values of the constants ($n$, $\alpha$) you can get the value (from a table or some software) of $k$ and then if you know $\sigma^2_0$ you can easily get $c$ as well.